# Как правильно настроить spring boot при установке его на IDE для создания REST-сервиса?

Tags: java, ide, rest, spring-boot, веб-служба

Народ, помогите пожалуйста! Переведите для нуба и чайника - чё означает следующее - как его начать грызть? Точнее - с чего ?

1. Спроектировать и реализовать REST сервис на Java.
2. Сервис должен получать данные с сервиса OSM (Open Street Map) который возвращает географические данные (множество координатных точек описывающих географическое положение объекта) какого-либо субъекта Российской Федерации.
3. Класс должен возвращать массив координат наибольшей части гео-объекта по его названию и типу (например название “Самарская область”, тип “region”), а также вычислять положение географического центра полученного массива координат.
4. Данные должны кэшироваться во избежание повторных запросов к OSM сервису.

Пример URL запроса для сервиса OSM:

1. [Для областей](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?state=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&country=russia&format=json&polygon_geojson=1)
2. [Для Фед. округов](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=%D0%9F%D0%A4%D0%9E&country=russia&format=json&polygon_geojson=1)

Спасите чайниковую душу )) Заранее благодарю, добрая душа !

Comment: Задание на собеседование?

Comment: Это задание на собеседование. Парень, изучи джаве для начала . Не суй пока что свой нос на незнакомые тебе технологии. Почитай что такое Мавен или грэдл

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну у вас уже все в тегах есть: тег "spring-boot", а значит идем в проект spring.io в раздел [уроки для чайников](https://spring.io/guides), для начала пробуем сделать проект [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), чтобы научится создать Rest сервисы с spring и spring-boot, потом попробуйте урок [Consuming a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/), чтобы научится получать данные с сервисов. Потом, внимательно читаем документацию [Spring](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) и [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), чтобы понять всю ту магию что описана в гайдах.

**P.S.** Но если вы проходите собеседование с таким заданием, то такие уроки вас не спасут, документация Spring сотни страниц и даже выучив большую часть и как-то сделав тестовое, простой практический вопрос в сторону сразу покажет вашу чайниковость. Ну и попав на работу вы сразу поплывете и испытательный срок закончится в первые же дни. По хорошему, нужны месяцы (и иногда годы) чтобы освоить Java + Spring хотя бы на уровне Junior'a. Поверьте, это не те технологии, которые можно за пару часов/дней выучить.

Comment: Viacheslav Vedenin, Тёзка, невероятная Благодарность ! Дай Бог здоровья и успехов! Буду "грызть" обозначенные материалы )) Я очень хочу победить эту "магию" !